# Is there a Ecto equivalent to an Active Record instance method in Ruby?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to figure out the best way to combine a `first_name` and `last_name` field in Ecto.

In rail's active record I can create an instance method like:

```
def name
  self.first_name + self.last_name
end
```

then when I create an active record instance I can use `User.name`. If I need to combine the first and last name or do some other logic to my Ecto model how would I go about doing that? This is a simple example and I could just concatenate it on the fly, but what if there was more complicated logic?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to pass a `Ecto.Schema`(usually obtained by calling some `Repo` method) to the method. From there access the required fields of the model, perform operations on them and return the result. Something like

```
  def name(user) do
    user.first_name <> user.last_name
  end
```

Place it in model `User.ex` file , then call `User.name(user)` from anywhere in your app. (`MyApp.User.name(user)` if `User` not aliased)

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same problem when I started writing Elixir. The instance method itch comes from thinking in objects, as Elixir is a functional language these things will feel wrong. The best advice I can give is to accept that this is the way it is and try to think in data instead of objects :)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a View concern in Ecto/Phoenix. It's not something that you would usually do in the schema.